# Swift generic reference type

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, weak

I'm having issues trying to constrain generic type requirements to just reference types. Here's some example code:

```
class WeakHolder<Element: AnyObject> {
    weak var element: Element?

    init(element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
}

protocol Animal: class { }

class Dog: Animal { }

let dog: Animal = Dog()
let holder = WeakHolder<Animal>(element: dog) // Error: Using "Animal" as a concrete type conforming to protocol 'AnyObject' is not supported.
```

If I change the generic requirement to `<Element: class>`, I get the error `class constraint can only appear on protocol declarations`.

Is this a limitation of generics? Marking a protocol as class is enough to have a weak reference to that protocol, is there no equivalent in generics?

Comment: Dog is not an AnyObject since Dog is a protocol

Comment: Based on my small experience this may be a limitation for generics as of swift 2.3. You may be able to fix this though by using classes instead of protocols

Comment: I need to use protocols in my implementation.

Comment: You're trying to create a class that's reusable for a huge part of your code aren't you?

Comment: I hope someone has a fix for this.

Comment: is doing this not acceptable? 
`class WeakHolder<Element where Element:Animal> {
    weak var element: Element?
    
    init(element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
}`

Comment: I'm using dependency injection in my project, so I work entirely with protocols. Yeah, I'm more looking for a way to constrain a generic to a reference type.

Comment: The problem is that [protocols don't conform to themselves](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself) – you can nearly always solve this problem with a type erasure, such as Rob shows in his answer to the Q&A. In your case, you'd want to make an `AnyAnimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you cannot have a generic type that is a protocol.

Writing out the syntax makes it clear how this works: 
`class/struct GenericType<TypeName: TypeConstraints> {}`

`let thing = GenericType<Type>() where Type is a class or struct that adheres to any constraints`

A Protocol Requiring adopting Types to be a class means any adopters are classes, but the Protocol *itself* is still not a Type.

It's possible generics could at some point support protocols, but it would require changing the general approach to either protocols or generics. Though your specific example may be possible with a smaller amount of work behind the scenes, so it's possible this may be implemented at some point.

You can take a look at [The Generics Manifesto](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md) if you want to see the direction they're going. Skimming it I didn't find anything directly related to your use case, but it's fairly specific so it may not be included in the parameters of the document.

Comment: Ah, the generalized class constraint is exactly what I'm looking for. Good to know that it's being considered for a future version of Swift.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution that worked in my particular case is the following:

```
class WeakHolder<Element: AnyObject> {
    weak var element: Element?

    init(element: Element) {
        self.element = element
    }
}

protocol Animal: class { }

class Dog: Animal { }

let dog: Animal = Dog()
let holder = WeakHolder<AnyObject>(element: dog as AnyObject)
```

When accessing element, I simply need to perform a downcast back to my protocol. Of course, I'll lose compile time safety when using this class with value types, but that's a non-issue in my situation.